# Get layer from graph, TensorFlow / Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I seek to access a layer's attributes from within a model's optimizer; I suppose one way to do so is via the Graph, which is accessible using e.g. `K.get_session()` (Keras/tf.Keras). However, I only find ops and tensors using `.get_operations()` or `._nodes_by_name` - not layer instances themselves. Is it possible to access layers via the default (or other) Graph?

---

**Example**: fetch `recurrent_regularizer` of the LSTM layer without accessing `model` (except `model.optimizer`):

```py
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM
from keras.models import Model
from keras.regularizers import l2

ipt = Input(shape=(120, 4))
out = LSTM(60, recurrent_regularizer=l2(1e-4), name='lstm_1')(ipt)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', loss='mse')
```

```py
>> print(vars(model.layers[1].cell.recurrent_regularizer))
{'l1': array(0., dtype=float32), 'l2': array(1.e-04, dtype=float32)}
```

---

**Context**: My [AdamW](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw) implementation allows specifying which weights to decay via a [dictionary](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/master/example.py#L18) of layer / weight names + a list of values; this does not scale well for very large or complex networks. It's more convenient for it  to work as a "drop-in" - only specifying decays in layer constructors, as usual. However, this information is stored in `layer._losses` or e.g. `layer.kernel_regularizer`, not in `weights` or `updates`, thus cannot be [accessed within](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/master/keras_adamw/optimizers_225.py#L138) (from attributes).

The optimizer will thus automatically determine [`wd`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw/blob/master/keras_adamw/utils.py#L73), *and* [zero](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/keras-adamw#weight-decay-1) all loss-based penalties (l2, etc).

---

**Update**: "context" problem is solved via a wrapper. Now the question is only about the question; is what's described "possible" in a non overly hackish manner?

Comment: As far as I know, `Layer`, `Model` and `Network` are just some encapsulations defined by Keras to simplify the definition and construction of a computation graph; therefore, their instances are not themselves stored in the computation graph. Rather, the ops they encapsulate would be stored and accessible in the graph. If you provide more details about what your final goal is (i.e. why, in the first place, do you want to access layers' instances only from optimizer/graph?), we might be able to help you better since maybe there would be another way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @today Your description is what I figured, but still hoping there's a non very hackish way of getting layers from within optimizers; updated to specify intent.

Comment: @today I also figure I can make a method to do this right before calling `.compile()` - but that's an extra step for the end-user.

Comment: @today Solved with a wrapper, quite elegantly. Now the question is only about itself; if you confidently doubt a non-hacky approach is possible, you can answer as such.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution comes to my mind for the moment. Good luck!